# I got 401 error in undelete method of vue request?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I make @vue/cli 4.0.5 app with reading data from Laravel 7 Backend REST API and 
and with softly deletion functionality in frontend part I have 2 methods 1) delete row 2) undelete row
Making similar implementation for both cases I got 401 error in 2) case and I can not find why.

1) Deleting row(works ok):

```
removeTask(id, task_name, soft_deletion/*, index*/) {
    console.log('removeTask soft_deletion::')
    console.log(soft_deletion)

    let confirm_message= "Do you want to delete permanently " + " '" + task_name + "' task ? It can not be restored !"
    if (soft_deletion) {
        confirm_message= "Do you want to mark for deletion " + " '" + task_name +
            "' task ? It would be unavailable in the app, but can be restored(undeleted) OR deleted permanently !"
    }

    if (!confirm(confirm_message)) {
        return
    }

    let credentials= this.credentialsConfig
    credentials.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.currentLoggedUserToken
    console.log('removeTask credentials::')
    console.log(credentials)

    axios.delete(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks/' + id, credentials).then((/*response*/) => {
        this.loadTasks()
        this.showPopupMessage('Tasks Editor', 'Task was '+(soft_deletion ? "softly" : "permanently")+' deleted successfully !'+( soft_deletion ?
            "But you can restore it or delete permanently" : "" ), 'success')
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        this.showPopupMessage('Tasks Editor', 'Error deleting task : ' + error.response.data.message, 'error')
    })

}, //removeTask(id, task_name, soft_deletion, index) {
```

and I see in console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hmOI.jpg

2) Undeleting row (raise 401 error)

```
unremoveTask(id, task_name/*, index*/) {
    console.log('unremoveTask id::')
    console.log(id)

    if (!confirm("Do you want to restore(undelete) " + " '" + task_name + "' task ?")) {
        return
    }

    let credentials= this.credentialsConfig
    credentials.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.currentLoggedUserToken

    console.log('unremoveTask credentials::')
    console.log(credentials)

    axios.put(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks/' + id+"/unremove", credentials).then((/*response*/) => {
        this.loadTasks()
        this.showPopupMessage('Tasks Editor', 'Task was deleted successfully', 'success')
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        this.showPopupMessage('Tasks Editor', 'Error deleting task !', 'error')
    })

}, //unremoveTask(id, task_name, index) {
```

and I see in console :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfwzv.jpg

I do not understand why error in 2)?
credentialsConfig if in settings file src/app.settings.js :

```
export const settingCredentialsConfig = {
    withCredentials:true,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true
    }
}
```

and in my vue file :

```
<script>
    import {settingCredentialsConfig} from '@/app.settings.js'
    ...


data() {
    return {
    credentialsConfig: settingCredentialsConfig,
    ...
```

any time I got copy of credentialsConfig var and add token to it.
In the console I see valid token headers.Authorization.

In /routes/api.php of my latavel app I have defined :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth',  'prefix' => 'adminarea', 'as' => 'adminarea.'], function ($router) {
    Route::resource('tasks', 'API\Admin\TaskController');
    Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'tasks'], function ($router) {
        Route::put('/{id}/unremove', 'API\Admin\TaskController@unremove_task');
```

In case of invalid undelete url I got 404 error...

Why error and how it can be fixed?

**UPDATED :**
Trying yo debug this issue I use clone function for creating of credentials var, 
which I use in request.

```
getClone: function (obj) {
    let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
    return copy
},
```

also I added 2 varaibles to which authorization_1 and authorization_2 ro which I assign

```
                let credentials= this.getClone(this.credentialsConfig)
                credentials.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.currentLoggedUserToken
                this.authorization_1= credentials.headers.Authorization
                console.log('removeTask credentials::')
                console.log(credentials)
                axios.delete(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks/' + id, credentials).then((/*response*/) => {
and

                let credentials= this.getClone(this.credentialsConfig)
                credentials.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.currentLoggedUserToken
                this.authorization_2= credentials.headers.Authorization
                console.log('unremoveTask credentials::')
                console.log(credentials)
                axios.put(this.apiUrl + '/adminarea/tasks/' + id+"/unremove", credentials).then((/*response*/) => {
```

and outputing these authorization_1 and authorization_2 vars on the page I can compare their content
and see that they have the same value like

```
‘Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWwtY3Rhc2tzLWFwaS5jb20vYXBpL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTkwNDE3NzcxLCJleHAiOjE1OTA0MjEzNzEsIm5iZiI6MTU5MDQxNzc3MSwianRpIjoiSHRjQmNPbUQwbjhKVHlqbyIsInN1YiI6MSwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.A3lZqX2hEaYGYuBoh9rDzjcyg4jEVkBXANRhAiUyZ0c’
```

I just wanted to check that with assigning credentials.headers.Authorization was not cut/modified anyway...

Any ideas why error ?

Thanks!

Comment: Set inner group before resource route.

Comment: Not Sure what Do you mean. Could you please give detailed responce ?

Comment: In main route group, set `Route::resource('tasks', 'API\Admin\TaskController');` at the end not at the beginning.

Comment: Do you mean that unremove method must be BEFORE resource, like (I do not use goups meanwhile):
    Route::put('tasks/{id}/unremove', 'API\Admin\TaskController@unremove_task');
    Route::resource('tasks', 'API\Admin\TaskController');
?
That did not help. I got the same 401 error.

Comment: Exactly, try that. I think there is collision with update route of resource and you should explicitly set custom method/route before other similar routes that could be seen in resource routes.

Comment: I tried and got the same 401 error.

Comment: Please, look at UPDATED

Comment: You've mixed request and response headers (i.e. those sent by client vs. those that server sends). Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers) page and pay attention also on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers) section. For example, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is server's response header. Compare other headers between your client and server as well.